# Flask app deployment - ImportError: No module named 'app'

Tags: python, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

Strange one - I've tried and tried to get this Flask app going - something seems to be going wrong.

`$ pwd` inside the Flask app gives:

/home/winduplordvexxos/winduplordvexxos.com/windupflaskvexxos

`$ ls` inside the Flask app gives:

```
__init__.py  __pycache__  vexxos.py  windupflaskvexxos.wsgi
```

`__init__.py` is empty.

**vexxos.py**:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def api():
 return 'Wind Up Lord Vexxos API'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**windupflaskvexxos.wsgi**:

```
activate_this = '/home/winduplordvexxos/winduplordvexxos.com/winduplordvexxos_env/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import os, sys

cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.insert(0, cwd)

try:
   from .vexxos import app as application
except Exception: #ImportError
   from vexxos import app as application
```

However, all I see on the front end is:

[image]

**/etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAlias flask.winduplordvexxos.com
        ServerAdmin admin@winduplordvexxos.com

        WSGIDaemonProcess windupflaskvexxos.com user=winduplordvexxos group=winduplordvexxos threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/winduplordvexxos/winduplordvexxos.com/windupflaskvexxos/windupflaskvexxos.wsgi

        <Directory /home/winduplordvexxos/winduplordvexxos.com/windupflaskvexxos/>
          WSGIProcessGroup windupflaskvexxos.com
          WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
          WSGIScriptReloading On
          Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Checking the apache error logs has given me:

```
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.650945 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859] mod_wsgi (pid=15561): Target WSGI script '/home/winduplordve$
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.651088 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859] mod_wsgi (pid=15561): Exception occurred processing WSGI scr$
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.657996 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.658060 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859]   File "/home/winduplordvexxos/winduplordvexxos.com/windupfl$
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.658071 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859]     from .vexxos import app as application
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.658098 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859] SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform rel$
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.658131 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859]
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.658146 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859] During handling of the above exception, another exception oc$
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.658156 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859]
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.658180 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.658229 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859]   File "/home/winduplordvexxos/winduplordvexxos.com/windupfl$
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.658248 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859]     from vexxos import app as application
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.658286 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103054321408] [remote 109.149.163.9:59859] ImportError: No module named 'vexxos'
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690252 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858] mod_wsgi (pid=15561): Target WSGI script '/home/winduplordve$
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690318 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858] mod_wsgi (pid=15561): Exception occurred processing WSGI scr$
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690468 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690515 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858]   File "/home/winduplordvexxos/winduplordvexxos.com/windupfl$
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690525 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858]     from .vexxos import app as application
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690549 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858] SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform rel$
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690566 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858]
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690573 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858] During handling of the above exception, another exception oc$
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690577 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858]
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690589 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690610 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858]   File "/home/winduplordvexxos/winduplordvexxos.com/windupfl$
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690619 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858]     from vexxos import app as application
[Fri Oct 13 23:05:14.690637 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15561:tid 140103087892224] [remote 109.149.163.9:59858] ImportError: No module named 'vexxos'
```

I've tried a number of things, try except on the module import etc but nothing seems to work...can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to tell mod_wsgi where your code is using the `python-path` option to `WSGIDaemonProcess`. Your import in the WSGI script file also looks wrong.

For `python-path` you likely want:

```
python-path=/home/winduplordvexxos/winduplordvexxos.com
```

The import should then be:

```
from windupflaskvexxos import app as application
```

or if `app` not pulled in by `__init__.py`, use:

```
from windupflaskvexxos.vexxos import app as application
```

Also read up on the preferred way of setting up a virtual environment with mod_wsgi. The way you are using is not the recommended way.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: Genius! This got it working - for reference: I used a combination of adding the python-path (I thought the working with virtual environments from the flask pocco docs here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/) was sufficient) and the `from windupflaskvexxos.vexos import app as application`. I think I was loosing it because the main website is served as a Django app.